# Display data from json array using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following code on index page the script contains part of the code that will call the data from test page

```
<div class="leftbox" id="proddisplay">

</div>

var onSubmit = function(e) {
  var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
  var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {
      txt: txtbox,
      hidden: hiddenTxt
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(returndata) {
      $('#proddisplay').html(returndata);
      console.log(returndata);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
    }
  });
};
```

From test.php i am getting json array that looks like this

```
[1,2,"text","text2"]
```

I want to display the json array data in a tabular form and display it inside the div. the view of table should be something like this (it will have some css of its own)

```
static text: 1
static text: 2
static text: text
static text: text2
```

static text will be given by me and remains the same throughout however the values of array would change. can anyone tell how i can do so

individually i can display the data from json, but here i also need to put json data in a table and then put that table within a div

Comment: @Gerald Versluis It just shows how to fetch data from json but i need to call individual value from json using ajax and then put it in a table and then put it inside a div

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to encode the array in php before sending to frontend, use json_encode() and then decode it in the success function using JSON.parse() . After just run a loop throught the array.

```
var onSubmit = function(e) {
 var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
 var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
 $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'test.php',
   data: {
     txt: txtbox,
     hidden: hiddenTxt
   },
   cache: false,
   success: function(returndata) {
     var returneddata = JSON.parse(returndata);
     var htmlData= '';
     for(var i=0; i<returneddata.length; i++){
        htmlData+= 'static text: '+returneddata[i]+' <br>';
     }
     $('#proddisplay').html(htmlData);
     console.log(returndata);
   },
   error: function() {
     console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
   }
 });
```

Comment: can i use this code without for loop as the static data will be different for every row but remains same for different data

Comment: The for loop just prints out each element. You cannot print out what you asked for without it. however you can alter the htmlData in order to take different data based on what is in the array

Comment: have you encoded the php array ? also check console for errors

Comment: yes i have encoded to json, and the console displays a proper json array, and i want to display the data in table form can u plz tell how to do it

Comment: then how did it stop your other script . I don't understand since it displays a proper json array it mean that the code that I provided has succesfully executed

Comment: the code is supposed to run on click of a button, along with it another action is performed, so this script runs but my other script does not i.e on click of a button 2 actions are to be performed but only one is getting performed

Comment: call your other script inside the success function of ajax, at the end. If the second script does something with the values from ajax that's the reason